# burning a Blu-Ray with Silicon Empire

Tags: linux, ubuntu, burning, blu-ray

I've been trying to burn a Blu-Ray disk from an .ISO. The .ISO was created by Nautilus (CD/DVD Creator). Since Brasero and K3B seem not to be able to burn a Blu-Ray on my system, I've installed `Silicon Empire` [link to site for this application](http://getsilicon.org/)  The error I get is the following.

```
Can't detect disc on "TSSTcorp DVDWBD TS-LB23D".
Please Insert an empty disc.
Free space needed: 23555MB
```

This application was mentioned at this link: [askubuntu.com question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43971/is-blu-ray-writing-support-reliable-yet/210277#210277) so I am giving it a try. The computer is the Samsung RF711 laptop. The optical drive is the one named in the error message: TSSTcorp DVDWBD TS-LB23D.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: K3B 2.0 has support for blu-ray. Time to update your software ;) (http://www.k3b.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a read-only Blu-Ray device. Confirm that by looking in K3b in the `Settings > Configure K3b > Devices` and look under the "Read Capabilities" and "Write Capabilities".